# Chain two answers Single

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, reactive

I need to link two RX Single responses - Retrofit to get an ArrayList with the two responses that return a List

I tried to process both answers with `Map`, `Flatmap`, but I have not achieved what I expected

```
final ArrayList <List<Consent>> listAllConsents = new ArrayList<>();
Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsent = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource.getConsents(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser());
Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsentByApp = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource.getConsentsByApp(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser());

responseDspConsentByApp.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    responseDspConsent.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                      .flatMap(consentData -> {
                          List<Consent> consentList = consentData;
                          listAllConsents.add(consentList);

                          return responseDspConsentByApp.map(consentDataByApp -> {
                              List<Consent> consentListByApp = consentDataByApp;
                              listAllConsents.add(consentListByApp);

                              return listAllConsents;
                          });
                      })
                      .subscribe(consentData -> {
                            Log.v("Entramoss", "Valor: " + listAllConsents.get(0).get(0).getTitle());

                            paintAllConsents(listAllConsents);
                      });
```

I need to have all the objects of the two responses in the arrayList so I can paint them later.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to do this.

1.You can use Observable.concat(Obs 1, Obs 2). The concat operator concatenates the observables and returns a single observable which first emits the items from the first observable then the second one. Source: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html

```
Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsent = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource
                       .getConsents(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser())
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsentByApp = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource
                       .getConsentsByApp(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser())
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable.concat(responseDspConsent.toObservable(),responseDspConsentByApp.toObservable())
                       .toList()
                       .doOnSuccess((list) -> {
                           paintAllConsents(list); 
                       })
                       .subscribe();
```

2.You can use the .concatWith operator which does the same thing as the concat operator but now it concats an observable to another without creating a new observable.

```
Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsent = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource
                       .getConsents(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser())
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsentByApp = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource
                       .getConsentsByApp(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser())
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

responseDspConsent.concatWith(responseDspConsentByApp)
                       .toList()
                       .doOnSuccess((list) -> {
                           paintAllConsents(list); 
                       })
                       .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

if your order do meter i suggest you to do .concat as @ebasha response but if your order doesn't meter i suggest you to use .merge  becase is much more faster than .concat because concat subscribe streams one by one and merge subscribe streams immediately

```
Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsent = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource
                   .getConsents(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser())
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Single<List<Consent>> responseDspConsentByApp = subscriptionCenterRemoteDataSource
                   .getConsentsByApp(Globals.getAuthorizationTokenUser())
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable.merge(responseDspConsent.toObservable(),responseDspConsentByApp.toObservable())
                   .toList()
                   .doOnSuccess((list) -> {
                       paintAllConsents(list); 
                   })
                   .subscribe();
```